# HiveMQ systemctl service not listening to port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mqtt, hivemq

I am trying to set up HiveMQ on my Amazon EC2 instance (ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20170414) using this guide: http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/latest/#hivemqdocs_installation_for_specific_operating_systems

After installing I can succesfully run HiveMQ using:

1. Change directory to HiveMQ directory `cd /opt/hivemq`
2. Execute startup script `./bin/run.sh`

HiveMQ will start running, and listening to port 1883 and I can connect and subscribe to the broker.

When I run HiveMQ as a systemctl service:

1. For Debian-based linux like Debian, Ubuntu, Raspbian using systemd `systemctl enable hivemq`

[It starts as a service withoutany issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO8I0.png)

However, when running `netstat -an|grep 1883` it does not show any activity. HiveMQ do not seem to listen to any ports and I can not connect with my MQTT client. What could be the issue?

Comment: does the log file show anything? 
you should be able to find it in `opt/hivemq/log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without any additional information my guess would be an issue with permissions.

`chown -R hivemq:hivemq /opt/hivemq` (changing the owner of the hivemq folder to the  hivemq user)

will resolve this issue

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the permissions as you suggested and the issues was solved.